# Forwarding does not work for some reason with WireGuard and NPM

Tags: vps, wireguard, npm, proxmox

I have a problem with the Nginx proxy manager and WireGuard. I have the following setup: A home server with Debian 12 and Proxmox behind a CNAT.

Therefore I use a VPS to get a public IP. My VMs are isolated from each other and connect to the VPS via WireGuard, so that my host system is also isolated from the VPS. I then route the traffic of the required ports directly to the vms via iptables.

The direct forwarding of the ports works perfectly. Now I want to host a VM as a central reserve proxy, which forwards HTTP and HTTPS to the other VMs. However, the forwarding does not work for some reason.

I can mutually ping the VM with NPM and the VM with the web service through the wg ips. But if I now want to forward `example.domain.org` to `192.168.4.101:264` in NPM, it does not work. If I use the local IP of the VM it works. It also works if I forward a service to the NPM host's own WireGuard IP.

Am I making a mistake here?

Summarized the desired proxy:

```
192.168.4.101:246 -> WG IP, does not work
192.168.8.101:246 -> Local IP, works 
192.168.4.102:81 -> Own WG IP on NPM works
```

Pinging works between:

```
192.168.4.1 (VPS) <-> 192.168.4.101 (VM web service) <-> 192.168.4.102 (VM NPM)
```

Here is the config:
VM with NPM

```
[Peer]
AllowedIPs =  192.168.4.1/32, 192.168.4.101/32
```

VM with webservice

```
[Peer]
AllowedIPs =  192.168.4.1/32, 192.168.4.102/32
```

VPS:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey= xxxx
ListenPort = 55107
Address = 192.168.4.1

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
#NGINX-Reverse-Proxy
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.102
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.102

PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
#NGINX-Reverse-Proxy
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.102
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.102

PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE

# VM with a webservice
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 192.168.4.101/32

# VM with NPM
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 192.168.4.102/32
```